# Flutter Capture event when app comes to Foreground from triggered Intent

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to pull off some basic stuff here. Scenario: I am checking for GPS status on `init()` using `isLocationServiceEnabled`. If the GPS is off, I'm showing a popup that redirects to Location settings using `AndroidIntent`. If hit back without turning on the GPS, I want to capture the event when my app comes to foreground. I guessed it has to do with the lifecycle and tried like below, nothing gets print on the console

```
    AppLifecycleState _notification;

    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
      setState(() {
        _notification = state;
        print('onResumed called 1');
        print(_notification);
      });
      if( state == AppLifecycleState.resumed){
        print('onResumed called 2');
      }
    }
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you extend class with `WidgetsBindingObserver` like so:

```dart
class _WhateverWidget extends State<WhateverWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver
```

and then initialize an instance like so:

```dart
@override void initState() { 
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
 super.initState(); 
} 

@override void dispose() { 
 WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
 super.dispose(); 
}
```

Comment: updated initState and dispose, I missed that part, yet no success :(

Comment: Try killing the app then flutter run, if that doesn't work could you maybe post the full code?

Comment: killing the app and then flutter run did the trick, thanks alot

Comment: if you don't mind, can you check this question posted by me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58994925/5209982 and share your insight on this?

Comment: sure but you should mark this answer as correct to close the question...